# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I've been studying SpringMVC and coded an example from http://shrestha-manoj.blogspot.com/2014/05/spring-mvc-maven-hibernate-crud-example.html and got this exception. Pretty much the code is copied and pasted on my IDE but I keep getting this error when I try to run **mvn tomcat7:run**. Can someone help me with this?

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
        at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:185)
        at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:386)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1794)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1865)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:431)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:138)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:188)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:341)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:507)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:146)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:163)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:135)
        ... 39 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter for property id in class com.org.bookstore.model.Book
        at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.createSetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:252)
        at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.getSetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:245)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getSetter(Property.java:326)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildPropertySetter(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:452)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:182)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:82)
        ... 44 more
```

this is my root-contex.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

       <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

       <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

           <property name="locations">
                 <list>
                      <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
                 </list>
           </property>
       </bean>

       <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
              destroy-method="close" 
              p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
              p:url="${jdbc.url}" 
              p:username="${jdbc.username}" 
              p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

       <bean id="sessionFactory"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
              <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

              <property name="packagesToScan">
                     <list>
                           <value>com.org.bookstore.model</value>
                     </list>
              </property>
              <property name="hibernateProperties">
                     <props>
                           <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                           <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                           <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                     </props>
              </property>
       </bean>

       <bean id="transactionManager"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
              <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
       </bean>

       <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
       <context:component-scan base-package="com.org.bookstore" />
</beans>
```

Comment: That is a very old example and not really how things are done any more. For a more modern approach see something like: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/. Additionally, while the suggested answer may fix your issue, is providing a setter for ID sensible given that it should be immutable? i.e. there should be no public API for client code to change it once assigned. Hibernate does not need setters so something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add setters for class Book.

```
    public class Book {
       ...

       public void setId(Long id) {
              this.id = id;
       }

       public void setName(String name) {
              this.name = name;
       }

       public void setCode(String code) {
              this.code = code;
       }

       public void setPrice(String price) {
              this.price = price;
       }

       public void setAuthors(String authors) {
              this.authors = authors;
       }

       public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
              this.isbn = isbn;
       }

       public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
              this.publisher = publisher;
       }

       public void setPublishedOn(Date publishedOn) {
              this.publishedOn = publishedOn;
       }
}
```